# Subtract Two Date Time Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to subtract two DateTime values:

I have *Start DateTime* `#2015-06-14 23:00:00#` *End Date Time* `#2015-06-15 01:01:00#`

I want to get the duration by time format like `HH:MM:SS` and update it in the duration column. I tried the following code but, it doesn't work.

```
update [ZainJTA].[dbo].[TBL_Justification]  
set [Justification_Event_Duration]=CONVERT(Datetime,(DateDiff("n",[Justification_From],[Justification_TO])/60/24),108)
```

Comment: i think you can subtract them directly which gives you the datetime type result. you can covert it to time if you want to. it really matters on display part. I would use datediff(second ...) and store it as integer.

Comment: What if duration greater then 24 hours?

Answer (score 3):

`DATEDIFF` returns an `INT`, so dividing it by two other `INT`s is going to give you - another `INT`, most likely zero.

Try:

```
CONVERT(Datetime,(DateDiff(s,[Justification_From],[Justification_TO])/60.0/60/24),108)
```

(the 60.0 will trigger conversion to a floating point format.)

However, it'd probably make more sense to *store* it as a number of seconds (integer), and only do the `CONVERT` when you output it to display.

To display as *just* the time, with no day/year part, you'll also need to do a second conversion:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(Datetime,
    (DateDiff(s,[Justification_From],[Justification_TO])/60.0/60/24),108),108)
```